# UI refresh looping a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, user-interface, dispatcher, begininvoke

I'm trying to do a System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rotation in Y axis simulating a card rotation, showing all the route.

The problem is that the UI only refreshes at the end.

*Simplified version of code*

**Call of method**

```
for (i=0; i<=180; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new a_dispatcher(() => {
            print_animation_of_card(card, i);
        }), 
        null);
}
```

**Method**

```
private void print_animation_of_card(System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle card)
{
    ...
    System.Windows.Media.PlaneProjection p = 
        card.Projection as System.Windows.Media.PlaneProjection;
    p.RotationY = i;
    card.Projection = p;
}
```

I have also tried to put the FOR into the method, with same result...

How can I do to show all the rotation movement of the System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are using `BeginInvoke()` instead of `Invoke`. This does not wait for one angle of rotation to complete before the next one is called, so the calls are all stacked on top of eachother.

Try it with `Dispatcher.Invoke()` or put the whole loop inside one `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` and see if the results are more to your satisfaction.

Comment: I'm working with Silverlight, so Invoke() method is not available...
I have tried putting the loop inside the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() but with no result, I have make it work by putting the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() into a Backgroundworker, but I would prefer to do it work without a multithreading...

Comment: @Korbert If you are not in a `BackgroundWorker` to begin with, then why use the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` at all? You should be able to manipulate the card `Rectangle` directly.

Comment: Yes, but I want to show all the Rectangle rotation animation to the user. If I do it normally without a Dispatcher I only see the final position. I thought I could show all the movement with a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(), am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have done it with a BackgroundWorker, thanks @Jay for the answers.

**Call of method**

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) =>
{
    print_animation_of_card(card);
};
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

**Method**

```
private void print_animation_of_card(System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle card)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 180; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new a_dispatcher(() =>
        {
            //same code as topic method code
        }),null);
    }
}
```